# Error: "user" defined in resolvers, but not in schema

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server

I'm trying to set up my schema for Apollo Server, and I'm running into an error.

What I'm trying is actually an attempt to fix a common and even more unhelpful message, using advice found here:

https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/1998

I'm not really sure how to reduce the code here, since I haven't been able to isolate the error more than this.

schema.js

```
import { makeExecutableSchema } from 'apollo-server-express'
import ApplicationSchema from './types'
import Resolvers from './resolvers'

export default makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs: ApplicationSchema,
  resolvers: Resolvers
})
```

resolvers/index.js

```
import user from './user'

export default {
  user
}
```

resolvers/user.js

```
import Joi from 'joi'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import { UserInputError } from 'apollo-server-express'
import { signUp, signIn } from '../validators'
import { User } from '../schemata' // mongoose schema
import * as Authentication from '../authentication'

export default {
  Query: {
    me: (root, args, { request }, info) => {
      Authentication.checkSignedIn(request)

      return User.findbyId(request.session.userId)
    },

    users: (root, args, { request }, info) => {
      Authentication.checkSignedIn(request)
      User.find({})
    },

    user: (root, args, { request }, info) => {
      const { id } = args

      Authentication.checkSignedIn(request)

      if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
        throw new UserInputError(`${id} is not a valid user ID.`)
      }

      return User.findById(id)
    }
  },

  Mutation: {
    signup: async (root, args, { request }, info) => {
      Authentication.checkSignedOut(request)
      await Joi.validate(args, signUp, { abortEarly: false })
      return User.create(args)
    },

    signIn: async (root, args, { request }, info) => {
      const { userId } = request.session

      if (userId) return User.findById(userId)

      await Joi.validate(args, signIn, { abortEarly: false })

      const user = await Authentication.attemptSignIn(args)

      request.session.userId = user.id

      return user
    },

    signOut: async (root, args, { request, response }, info) => {
      Authentication.checkSignedIn(request)

      return Authentication.signOut(request, response)
    }
  }
}
```

types/index.js

```
import root from './root'
import user from './user'

export default [
  root, 
  user
]
```

types/root,js

```
import { gql } from 'apollo-server-express'

export default gql`
 type Query {
   _: String
 }

 type Mutation {
   _: String
 }

 type Subscription {
   _: String
 }
```

types/user.js

```
import { gql } from 'apollo-server-express'

export default gql`
  type User {
    id: ID!
    email: String!
    username: String!
    name: String!
    password: String!
    createdAt: String!
  }

  extend type Query {
    me: User
    user(id: ID!): User
    users: [User!]!
  }

  extend type Mutation {
    signUp(email: String!, username: String!, name: String!): User
    signIn(email: String!, password: String!): User
    signOut: Boolean
  }
```

Hopefully, schema.js should run without errors and the resulting executable schema will work well with Apollo Server.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `resolvers` object should be structured like what's inside `types/user.js`, i.e.:

```
{
  Query: {
    // Query fields
  },
  Mutation: {
    // Mutation fields
  },
  // etc.
}
```

The `resolvers` object should be a map of type names. Instead, because of the way your imports are set up, you're ending up with:

```
{
  user: {
    Query: {
      // Query fields
    },
    Mutation: {
      // Mutation fields
    },
    // etc.
  }
}
```

Because this is what you're passing in as your `resolvers`, Apollo assumes you're trying to map resolvers for a type called `user`, which doesn't exist in your schema, so it throws the error you're seeing.

If you want to combine multiple resolver objects, you need to recursively merge them using something like `lodash`'s [merge](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#merge):

```
import user from './user'
import foo from './foo'
import _ from 'lodash'

export default _.merge(
  user,
  foo
)
```

Comment: daniel, it doest fix issue

Comment: It did for the OP. There could be any number of other issues with your code. Please post a new question with a reproducable example.

Comment: Much better to use `mergeResolvers` from `graphql-tools/merge`: https://www.graphql-tools.com/docs/merge-resolvers